# How can I assign work to a specific cluster by using its name

Tags: python, distributed-computing, dask, dask-distributed

I have made a local cluster with 8 worker. Now I want specific task to be submitted to specific workers. How can I do it in local cluster?

Answer (score 2):

https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.run

Restrict computation to particular workers with the workers= keyword argument.

```py
>>> c.run(os.getpid, workers=['192.168.0.100:9000',
...                           '192.168.0.101:9000'])  # doctest: +SKIP
{'192.168.0.100:9000': 1234,
 '192.168.0.101:9000': 4321}
```

You can also do this with `resources`:
https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html#example